# Why do developers use "_" while using get and set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, getter-setter

I know that using an underscore is just a convention to define private variables in JavaScript. But I came across a use case [while using a class] where use of `_` seems mandatory to make the code work! My question is how `_` is used under the hood by `get` and `set`.

The below code throws an error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }

  set name(val) {
    this.name = val;
  }
}

let user = new User("Jhon");
console.log(user.name);
```

Now, if I use `_` the code works!

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name; // Added "_" here
  }

  set name(val) {
    this._name = val; // Added "_" here
  }
}

let user = new User("Jhon");
console.log(user.name);
```

Comment: The `_` doesn't have special meaning here either. You just need to store your values in a data property with *any other name*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look at this piece of code logically:

```
get name() {
    return this.name
}
```

You read `object.name`. To return a value, the `get name()` getter reads `this.name`, which, in turn, resolves to `get name()`. And now, welcome to the infinite loop.

Hence, you need a separate variable name (to store the actual content of `name`) than the getter's name. That would be a private variable, and it has become a convention to prepend an underscore in these cases.

Answer (score 6):

Your first snippet uses the same name for the getter/setter as the property you try to assign to. So, in the constructor, when you do

```
this.name = name;
```

you are invoking the `name` setter, which does:

```
this.name = val;
```

again invoking the `name` setter, which recursively calls itself until the stack overflows.

Using a different variable name for the *actual property* the data is stored in (compared to the getters/setters) allows for the code to work as intended. It doesn't have to be prefixed with an underscore - pretty much *anything* other than the same name used by the getters/setters will work.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.actualProperty;
  }

  set name(val) {
    this.actualProperty = val;
  }
}

let user = new User("Jhon");
console.log(user.name);
```

The `_` before a property name is generally meant to indicate that the property is meant to be private, and that only the class itself should access it, but it's no guarantee - users of the class are still free to reference `user._name` if they wish. If you want *actual* private data for each instance, you should define the class in a closure with a WeakMap that holds the private data:

```js
const User = (() => {
  const data = new WeakMap();
  return class User {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    get name() {
      return data.get(this);
    }

    set name(val) {
      data.set(this, val);
    }
  }
})();

let user = new User("Jhon");
console.log(user.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `_` affix is commonly used for private properties.

You use private properties in addition to getters and/or setters when you want to be able to control how and when you can update a property, or add side effects to those actions.

You should also have a private property declaration in your class

```
class User {
  private _name; // <-- here

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(val) {
    this._name = val;
  }
}
```